# I cant fire useEffect from query when i use history.goBack()

Tags: reactjs, search, browser-history

I am learning react and materialUI, and the app I’m building its about search in the amdb api and bring some data.

In my "search component" I set it up that when the user writes something automatically it writes on the query and fire the useEffect with this query.

The first search works perfect, I list all the result, and you could go on the movie that you want. Thats brings you to other component, renderMovie, and it has a button to previous page (I set it up using history.goBack() )

The problem appears when I go back; I do go back to search component, but I lose the search I did before go in. I have the query on the url, but I can’t fire the useEffect.

I tried changing the dependencies in the effect, but nothing seems to work. I tried using useMemo too, but I can’t make it works because I don’t have a function itself (I mean the only function i have is the handleInputChange).

Could you give some advice? How could I do it? What approach could I use? Or maybe could you give me other ideas to try?

Thanks in advance!

This is my seachComponent, if you have some questions...

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    import { Container, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
    import queryString from "query-string";
    
    
    import MovieCardItem from '../components/MovieCardItem';
    import PaginationComp from '../components/PaginationComp';
    import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../assets/Search.svg";
    import { API_KEY, URL_API } from '../utils/constants';
    
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
            '& > *': {
                margin: theme.spacing(1),
                width: '25ch',
            },
        },
        bigContainer: {
            margin: '1rem auto 3rem auto',
            textAlign: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        media: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            margin: '1rem auto',
        },
        textField:{
            width: '100%'
        },
        noResults: {
            margin: '0 auto',
        }
    }));
    
    
    export default function SearchPage() {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const history = useHistory();
        const location = useLocation();
    
        const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
    
        const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);
        const [showMovieList, setShowMovieList] = useState(false);
        const [showNoResult, setShowNoResult] = useState(false)
    
        const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
        const [pageTotal, setPageTotal] = useState(1);
        const [showPagination, setShowPagination] = useState(false);
        
    
        const handleInputChange = (e) => {
            setFirstRender(false);
            if (e.target.value === ' ') {
                e.target.value = '';  
                return null
            }
            const urlParams = queryString.parse(location.search);
            urlParams.s = e.target.value; 
            if(e.target.value === '') {
                setShowPagination(false);
                setFirstRender(true)
                history.push(`/buscar`)    
                setShowMovieList(false);
            } else {
                history.push(`?${queryString.stringify(urlParams)}`);
                setShowMovieList(true);
                setShowPagination(true);
            }
        }
        
        
        useEffect(() => {
            if (firstRender) return null;
    
            const getSearch = async () => {
                const searchValue = queryString.parseUrl(location.search);
                const { s } = searchValue.query;
                if(s === undefined) return null;
                    
                const response = await fetch(`${URL_API}/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=es-ES&query=${s}&page=${page}` );
                const movies = await response.json();
                // console.log(movies)
    
                if (movies.results.length === 0) {
                    setShowNoResult(true);
                    setShowMovieList(false);
                } else {
                    setShowNoResult(false);
                    setPageTotal(movies.total_pages);
                    setMovieList(movies.results);
                }
            }
           
            getSearch();
            // eslint-disable-next-line   
        }, [location.search, page])
    
        return (
            <>
                <Grid container spacing={0} alignItems="center" className={classes.bigContainer}>
                    <Grid item xs={5} sm={4} md={3} className={classes.smallContainer} >
                        <Logo className={classes.media} />
    
                        <form 
                            className={classes.root} 
                            noValidate autoComplete="off"
                            onSubmit={ (e) => e.preventDefault() }
                        >
                    
                            <TextField 
                                id="outlined-basic" 
                                label="Buscar pelicula..." 
                                variant="outlined" 
                                className={classes.textField}
                                onChange={ handleInputChange }
                            />
                           
                        </form>
    
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
    
                <Container >
                    <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
                        {
                            (showMovieList || movieList.length===0 ) ? (
                                movieList.length === 0 ? null  : (
                                    movieList.map( (movie) => (
                                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={movie.id} >
                                            <MovieCardItem movie={movie} key={movie.id} />
                                        </Grid>
                                    ))
                                )
                            ) : (null)
                        }
                        {
                            showNoResult && <p className={classes.noResults}>No hay resultados para mostrar</p>
                        }
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
    
                {
                    (showPagination && pageTotal > 1 && !showNoResult ) && 
                        (
                            <PaginationComp pageTotal={pageTotal} setPage={setPage} page={page} />
                        )
                }
            </>
        );
    }
```

And this is the button of my renderMovie

```
    <Button 
        variant="contained" 
        color="primary"  
        href="#contained-buttons"
        size="large"
        component="div"
        onClick={() => history.goBack()}
    >
                                Volver
                            </Button>
```

Comment: all fetch just depends on location.search, include current page,
Pagination.page, TextField.defaultValue initialized from location.search,
Pagination.setPage, TextField.onChange trigger location.push to change url

Comment: Theoretically, all searches are based on the URL and listen for changes in the URL. All component initialization values come from the URL, and the URL is directly modified when component value changes are made

Comment: in your case, not work may cause'd by `if (firstRender) return null;`, remove this line , and TextField.onChange debounce change location.search, seems ok

Answer (score 0):

When navigate away, your searchComponent page got unmounted, and `history.goBack()` will make your page component re-mount, so it's the same as rendering fresh page.

For solution, you might need update sync url-query param while user type like when user input `action` you update url to like `/movie/search?q=action`

Alternatively, you could persist user search in localStorage or so and read the value when user enter the search page.